# How to decrease black colour for ColorMatrix

Tags: android, colormatrix

[image][image]I have used this code snippet,how i can reduce black color over here.

```
 ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
        colorMatrix.setSaturation(0);
        float brightness = (float)(bar.getProgress());//it can be 0-128
        float m = 205f;
        float t = -255*brightness;
        ColorMatrix threshold = new ColorMatrix(new float[] {
                m, 1, 0, 1, t,
                0, m, 1, 1, t,
                1, 0, m, 1, t,
                0, 1, 0, 1, 0
        });
```

After above implementation image become too black.

Comment: what does `reduce` mean? do you want to fade it out (decrease the alpha) or change into another color or what?

Comment: Check attached image.
I want to make proper black and white.

Comment: make proper? what is "proper"? do you want black color to change into red for example? what does `reduce` mean?

Comment: Please check i have attached iOS black & White image with GPUImage filter.
I want my image near to that so object look visible.

Comment: so you want to adjust the brightness or what? can you answer what `reduce` means?

Comment: I want to reduce black color from image

Comment: ok you need someone else to answer your question